Javascript template literals hide event.target elements?
Easy enough to work around but curious about why this is happening
console.log(e.target); // returns <input form="survey-entry-form" name="zip-code" id="zip-code">
console.log(`${e.target}`); // returns [object HTMLInputElement]

I haven't noticed this in any other situation with template literals
I tried with the template literal, then just typed e.target into the console and got what I expected.

I added a response to the question in the duplicate post above.
